# React: remove generate unique id for id and class

Tags: reactjs

I've a simple question. I'm working in React, and sometimes, I need to surchage a specific css. But, React generate me an uniq Id for class and id, for example : 
For my class "content", it generates content-y1201. I would like how can i remove that, and have just "content" ?

I don't want what's npm package cause that. Can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: Can you show that? Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: Possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+modules+global

Comment: React doesn't do that. It's probably CSS modules that do. Could you share an affected component code?

Comment: Yes, you're right ! It's the npm package "q". Is there a way to disable the generation in somes cases ? I specify you that this module is just installed and not imported.

Thank you for your answer !

Comment: I remove the npm package q, and i have always the same problem. So it's not q..